# scatter plot interpretation

Tags: regression

I am stack with a simple question:
I run a simple linear regression model and i get a b coefficient which is statistically significant different from zero but my scatter plot does not provide me with any pattern. How should i interpret this?

[image]

Comment: Which plot are you referring to ? The residuals vs predicted values ? What pattern are you expecting to see ?

Comment: You could look at the estimates themselves?

Comment: I have difficulty believing that the linear regression in the bottom scatterplot has a significant coefficient.  Could you supply the relevant output?

Comment: @whuber it looks like that plot is one of the diagnostic plots (residuals vs fitted values) not a scatterplot of the data.

Comment: @Robert Sure enough, you're right.  That means we likely don't have the information needed to answer this question except in the most generic way.